# How can I print specific name files from filesystem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So I can print all the files in a folder but i'd like to print the files that I want. What I mean by that is that I will input for example Mineract, if I have in the folder, for example minecraft_server,mineract launcher. It would print all the names with Minecraft in they're names so it would print Minecraft server and Mineacraft Launcher

I've tried putting it in a for loop. But i can not do the I position of path it's not possible.

```
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
{
    cout << entry.path() << endl;
}
```

That would just print all the files.

***UPDATED CODE*** (still doesn't work).
search - What ever the user inputs

```
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) { 
if (entry.path().string().find(search) != string::npos) {
                    cout << entry.path().string() << endl;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Use something like `entry.path().string()` (or `entry.path().filename().string()`) and then use the methods available on `std::string` (e.g. `substr` or `starts_with` or `ends_with`) to see if it matches one of the (specific) names you are looking for.

Comment: @Christian.K you are right a guy gave me a really good answer here but it doesn't seem to work he used what you seggested and I would of do the same as he did

Comment: You've spelt "Minecraft" in three different ways here. Please take more care over your post and write down _exactly_ and _precisely_ what it is that you want to do, to avoid getting an inapplicable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly which I seriously doubt, you want to loop through a folder and its subfolders and only do something for files that contain a certain string.

The following (off top of my head) would work

```
#include <experimental/filestream>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filestream
for (auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(yourPath)) 
{
   if(file.path().u8string().find(yourString) != std::string::npos)
       do your stuff
}
```

This example comes straight from code I used for 8 weeks straight and it never failed on me:

```
for (auto file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("./"))
                {
                    //std::cout << file.path().u8string() << std::endl;
                    if (includedFiles.find(file.path().u8string()) != includedFiles.end()
                        || skipFile(config, files, &file)
                        || file.path().u8string().find((*config)["testFile"].get<std::string>()) != std::string::npos
                        || file.path().u8string().find((*config)["outputFile"].get<std::string>()) != std::string::npos
                        || matchRegex(&fileOrder, &file.path().u8string())) // Last one does ordering
                    {
                        //if (file.path().u8string().find("ValidateModel") != std::string::npos)
                        //{
                        //  std::cout << "skipped model string " << file.path().u8string() << std::endl;
                        //}
                        continue;
                    }

                    includedFiles[file.path().u8string()] = true;
                    std::cout << file.path().u8string() << std::endl;
                    functor(file);
                }
```

Full code minus the library is available at github: https://github.com/erikknaake/IseProjectSQLFileCombiner/blob/master/SQLFileCombiner.cpp

When you know the name of the folder:

```
std::string path = std::cin;
for (auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) 
    {
           do your stuff
    }
```

Maybe you need to prepend a /

Comment: Pretty sure you understood it right but it doesn't work doesn't even print anything if i do for example cout << "yes";

Comment: I used the library https://github.com/nlohmann/json to parse json, the code assumes that all json fields exist. Compiled with Visual Studio 2019. Feel free to do a PR that adds that library ;-)

Comment: I don't understand why the first code you did is wrong though all I want is to search if the user input minecraft it would find all the files in the folder named "minecraft"

Comment: Where is the input of the user as well? what should i replace it with and what is "Test file" and "Output File"

Comment: This code uses a json file called ParserConfig.json as its import, this code is way overkill for you, but I think you can cut out snippets you need, mainly from the `forEveryFileInOrder` function. Also take a look at my edited answer since it might cotain the exact solution for you.

Comment: your other "When you know the name of the folder:" is bad because the user has to input C:/user/fdf/path it's long.  I really don't understand why the first code you gave me doesn't work
I did this code you can see it above by the title "Updated code"

Comment: does that work or not? If not what path are you using?

Comment: Look at the code above p.s thank you for sticking by and helping me

Comment: The custom path could work but the user will have to type so much like he'll have to type C:/Users/nont/OneDrive/Desktop or something like that

Comment: That is where relative paths come in, if you run the code inside C:/Users/nont/OndeDrive, the user would only have to type `./Desktop`

Comment: Dude the user could open the things in the desktop but I want him to be able to search things in it